# Save sql result to variable using php

Tags: php, sql

I have this query:

```
$result = "SELECT MAX(N) as maxid FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(id_f, 2,len(id_f) -1)  as N 
    From formas  WHERE id_f LIKE '%D%'
    ) t" ;  
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $result) or die(odbc_error());
```

Now, if i put the query in SQL SERVER i get the correct result.
What i need is to save the maxid as a variable.. how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of that post, @Scorpi0 . But note that the technology (mysql_*) in that post is out-dated.

Comment: Well, i didn't post that one! I tried to search here and couldn't get an answer..

Comment: Please, this is not mysql, i work with odbc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the function [odbc_fetch_array](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php).

```
$result = "SELECT MAX(N) as maxid FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(id_f, 2,len(id_f) -1)  as N 
    From formas  WHERE id_f LIKE '%D%'
    ) t" ;  
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $result) or die(odbc_error());
$info = odbc_fetch_array($res);
$content[] = $info;
$maxN = $content[0]
```

For a multiple rows query, you need to encapsulate the function in a while loop :

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) 
{ 
    print_r($row); 
}
```